# Are There Any Standards for building pin code authorization?

Tags: authorization

We're going to add a pin authorization feature to our website. So, I'm wondering a question, how to make it secure? As I understand, Apple/Windows after first user login link pincode to a specific device. I'm thinking about storing part of data to cookies (to link it to a physical device).
The question is: are there any standards for such authorization systems? Or any large websites which are using them?
What should be pin lifetime? How many times may they be used?

Comment: I'm not really sure what this buys you in terms of security.  Why do you need PIN authentication?  Is it a usability concern, or is it an attempt at 2FA?

Comment: This is a usability concern: boss wants an easy login way "like Apple", and I want it to be still secure.

Comment: What kind of clients are you dealing with.  Just web browsers?

Comment: yes, only web browsers

Answer (score 2):

I think your boss may be misunderstanding the situation it a bit.  If a user is logging in a website using a web browser and convenience is a major factor to them, they will most likely have their browser/password safe save their username and password for them.  With this scenario, the user doesn't have to do anything but click a button in their browser.  All the PIN will do is make things more complicated for the user, annoy them, and will very likely make your system less secure (due to implementation flaws).

To answer your questions above:

- The NIST is probably the best bet as far as standards go.  Since this
  is basically a password, look for their password complexity
  requirements (Note, a PIN will fail pretty much every one of these)
- I  am not aware of any large websites using them.  The only place
  PINS    are really used is on mobile phones, and they are a different
  use    case all together.

The bottom line:  The proposed solution is going to cost money to provide no benefit, and will weaken your security and potentially leave the company liable to a lawsuit.